# cp210x ttyUSB0: failed to get comm status

Tags: usb, tty, serial-port, dmesg

Running Ubuntu 16:04. I have bought a serial device(ttl) to USB called cp210x.
It works most of the time, but after a while it can suddenly disconnect. 
There are two ways to activate it again, one is to restart ubuntu, the other is to try a different USB-port. The latter only works sometimes.

Running the following command

> dmesg | egrep --color 'serial|'

Outputs something like:

```
[ 1618.701835] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1619.033496] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[ 1619.033499] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1619.033501] usb 1-1: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 1619.033503] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 1619.033504] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 1620.073501] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[ 1620.073511] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[ 1620.073519] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[ 1620.074985] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[ 1620.074994] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[ 1620.075022] cp210x 1-1:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 1620.089846] usb 1-1: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 4864.852078] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed to get comm status: -110
[ 4869.971623] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x7 status: -110
[ 4875.095122] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x12 status: -110
[ 4880.214602] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -110
[ 4892.497449] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -110
[ 4892.497454] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x_open - Unable to enable UART
[ 4897.616984] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -110
[ 4897.616989] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x_open - Unable to enable UART
[ 4905.088772] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 4905.088926] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 4905.088940] cp210x 1-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

From 1620.xxx to 4864.xxx it seems to work, however I cannot activate it again after it failed to get comm status.